# website dropbdown button component name

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Does anyone know the name of the of the a webpage component which acts as an expandable read-only textarea.

So basically, the component initially looks like a button with a title and an arrow marker indicating that there is more to view if the user clicks below, then once the user clicks on the arrow, the button's area expands and displays text below.

I know this is vague but any references or ideas would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

accordion (may be) here is an example
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/accordion-menu

here is an example of text only accordion

```
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/l1bPQ
```

Comment: That's very close, but would it be possible to get each accordion to only include text and not links?

Comment: Just change the links to text: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-primary"></span>Articles`

Comment: @LM23 i have updated my answer with sample code. Please have a look. and if this is what you expected please accept my answer. thanks.

Comment: @Dipesh, what is the difference between the accordion and a drawer.

Comment: @LM23 drawer, i think is alternative for off canvas menu
have a look at this example
https://codepen.io/nwest88/pen/PwwZpv